Safenet authentication client not detecting safenet token in vmware virtual machin
I am trying to add a safenet token to a vmware esxi vm. The token device is showing in device list of windows. but safenet authentication client tool is showing no token is connected.
Now need to know is there any limitation of safenet token detection in virtual machine? If no, what is the procedure to detect in client tools. I am not getting resource in web regarding the issue.
TIA.

How? What? What is the token? How is it supposed to be used? What have you done to attach it to the VM?

Via USB. Used this method to connect USB token to VM. 1.Power-up VM
2.VM > Edit settings > Virtual Hardware
3.Add other device > USB device
4.Select Aladdin Knowledge Token JC > Save

Any error messages? Is the device showing up in the VM?

No error message. Device is showing in device list. But the client software is not detecting the device. If i connect the token device to a physical machine then there is no issue to detect it by client software.
